# Display Word Count in Blog Post with Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am wondering how to create a template tag that will get the word count for an entire blog post in Wagtail. I have looked around and seen some different ways to do with with python, but not quite sure how to do it with wagtail given views are often abstracted away. It seems like the query also gets more complex given that in many cases there can be multiple parts to a wagtail template (intro, body, etc.) that the creator might want to count.

I noticed there is also [a nice package](https://github.com/takeflight/wagtail-charcount) that does this in the admin for you, but I would like to display it on the user side.

I am guessing this is a pretty simple answer, but am still not familiar with passing new variables to templates in Wagtail without a view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template tag wouldn't be the best approach here - templates are concerned with the presentation of the page, but the word count is a meaningful property of the page data that's independent of any particular presentation. I'd suggest defining `word_count` as a method on your page model instead - then it's always available as `page.word_count()`, or `{{ page.word_count }}` in templates. Here's an example of how it could work (using the `str.split` method, which splits on spaces, as a cheap-and-cheerful way of getting a word count):

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField()
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock()),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])

    def word_count(self):
        count = len(self.intro.split())
        for block in self.body:
            if block.block_type == 'paragraph':
                count += len(str(block.value).split())

        return count
```

Comment: Thanks for the great example of a simple way to get a word count. This works, but I get a weird error when trying to get the length of a rich text field.

 `'RichText' object has no attribute 'split'` 

Should I iterate over the rich text field to look for headers and paragraphs only somehow?

Comment: Ah, sorry - looks like that error's coming from the RichTextBlock in the StreamField. It needs to be explicitly converted to a string, using `str(block.value)`. Updated now...

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the fix! Anyone looking at this in the future I added a couple lines to @gasman 's script to make a quick word count and time to read script.  
`def word_count(self):  
  count = 0  
  for block in self.body:  
   if block.block_type == 'introduction':  
    count += len(block.value.split())  
   elif block.block_type == 'content':  
    count += len(str(block.value).split())  
  self.count = count  
  return count  
  
 def reading_time(self):  
  words = self.count  
  speed = 225  
  time = math.ceil(words/speed)  
  
  return time`